# What is wrong with this Ajax call?

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

```
I'm trying to generate the qr code and pop up it in mvc. Below is the code



    $("#generateQRCode").on('click', function (e) {

    //TODO prevent deafualt
    var Details =
    {
        cityId: $('#city_Id').val(),
        cityTypeId: $('#Type_Id').val(),
        busId: $('bus_Id').val(),
        serialId: $('#serial_Id').val(),
        makeId: $('#make_Id').val()

    }

        $.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        async: true,
        type: 'GET',

       // headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val() },
        url: "/Home/Index/",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(Details),
        //processData: false,
        //cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.result === true)
            {
                debugger;
                $("#afterActionConfirmationModal").modal('show');

            }
            else {
                debugger;
                alert("error1");
            }
        },
        error:
            alert("error2"),
    });
    //controller


[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index(object details)
{
}
```

I'm always getting the error2 alert code block when i debug and then it goes to action method and object "details" values is filled with value 0.No error 
message is being shown. Please help me out

Answer (score 4):

> I'm always getting the error2 alert

Because this doesn't do what you think it does:

```
error: alert("error2")
```

This doesn't set the `alert()` as the `error` callback handler.  This executes the `alert()` *immediately* and sets its *result* (which is `undefined`) as the `error` callback handler.  So the `alert()` will be shown whether there's an error or not, because it'll be shown before the AJAX call even executes.

Wrap it in a function to use as the callback, just like the `success` callback handler:

```
error: function () {
    alert("error2");
}
```

---

**Update:** From the comments below, it seems you're also expecting a lot out of the `object` type in C#.  That type has no useful properties, so there's nowhere to find the values you're posting to the server.  Use a custom type:

```
public class Details
{
    public int cityId { get; set; }
    public int cityTypeId { get; set; }
    public int busId { get; set; }
    public int serialId { get; set; }
    public int makeId { get; set; }
}
```

And use that class:

```
public IActionResult Index(Details details)
```

You may also need to replace `JSON.stringify(Details)` with just `Details`, since you probably want to send the object itself rather than a serialized string.

Comment: But even after this change its not posting the parameter values to action methods and after returning from action method its displaying error2 popup

Comment: @krity: That sounds like a different problem.  For the action method itself... What are you expecting to be in `details`?  An `object` has no useful properties.  You should be using a specific model type there, or perhaps individual method parameters.

Comment: its a object which will have values for cityId,cityTypeId,busId,serialId,makeId from the Textbox and i have a model defined in the class file "details"

Comment: @krity: But the type `object` doesn't have any of those properties.  It sounds like you just forgot to make a model with those properties on it.  Do you know how to make a class in C#?  Try making one which matches the properties you expect and use that instead of `object`.  (It's also worth noting that the code you're showing here doesn't even compile, since your method doesn't return anything, so the compiler would definitely be telling you the problem.)

Comment: I have a model class file for it

Comment: @krity: I've updated the answer.  Though if you have a model class then you should definitely use that class.

Comment: I'm using it in action method @David,here i forgot to mention it in question

Comment: @krity: If the code you're using is different from the code you're showing us then that drastically limits this community's ability to help you.  Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  As for the model type, you can still refer to the example in this answer.  There's a sample model provided (assuming values are `int` based on the "id" in their names, change types as needed for your model) as well as a suggested change to how you send that data to the server.